# The most applicable areas in Theoretical Computer Science

Tags: soft-question

I just wanted to know areas in common to Theoretical Computer Science which have a lot of carrer prospects outside of academia. I specifically wanted to know because I am interested in almost all areas of TCS equally, so why not choose a field for PhD which is more vibrant in terms of carrer choice.
Inspired by this question  [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162125/what-areas-of-pure-mathematics-research-are-best-for-a-post-phd-transition-to-in)

My guesses are
1) Information Theory, all major communication companies and companies which need storage
2) Cryptography (Specifically protocols and construction of new/better codes)
3) Algorithmic Game Theory (Companies like Google are investing a lot in it)
4) Formal Verification(But i think it is a very niche area focussed in Europe)

Comment: Don't do a PhD in theoretical computer science. There are many other areas of computer science which are much more practical.

Comment: No I love theory and only theory, from complexity theory to algorithms, but right now I am too open and dont have any particular fixation for any particular area,so i just wanted to keep track of areas where the carrer prospects are relatively beter.

Answer (score 2):

Anything to do with Machine Learning has a lot of career prospects because you could be employed by either finance or technology companies in general.

Comment: Yes, Statistical Learning Theory has quite a bit of applications.